# How to read tracebacks of circular imports?

Tags: python

I have an import error and the corresponding traceback but I can't wrap my head around reading the traceback correctly. If I just look at the file names, will they form a circle or is it more a lasso shape?

Here is my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "log_server_startup.py", line 4, in <module>
    from server.routes import version, settings
  File "/PycharmProjects/Routing/server/routes.py", line 12, in <module>
    from api3.factories.osrm_routing import fetch_osrm_routing_from_request
  File "/PycharmProjects/Routing/api3/factories/osrm_routing.py", line 3, in <module>
    from api3.request import Request
  File "/PycharmProjects/Routing/api3/request/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from api3.request.factories.request import request_from_request_json
  File "/PycharmProjects/Routing/api3/request/factories/request.py", line 6, in <module>
    from api3.request import Waypoint
ImportError: cannot import name 'Waypoint' from partially initialized module 'api3.request' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

It mentions 5 files:

1. `"log_server_startup.py"`
2. `"/PycharmProjects/Routing/server/routes.py"`
3. `"/PycharmProjects/Routing/api3/factories/osrm_routing.py"`
4. `"/PycharmProjects/Routing/api3/request/__init__.py"`
5. `"/PycharmProjects/Routing/api3/request/factories/request.py"`

Where is the circle?

Comment: The circle is _beyond_ that point, because it is unable to initialize the module `api3.request` because there's a circular import

Comment: I don't get it.